# Creating scroll left button next to scroll right button

Tags: jquery, scroll

Apologies if this question is stupid but I am new to jquery.

I have a webpage with horizontal scroll that navigates with two buttons on top. The button that scrolls right works perfectly but the button that scroll left will always take you to the beginning of the page no matter what. Wondering what is wrong with my code!

Webpage: http://alicelanyang.com/richardhyatt/women.html

The script is, with arrow-button being the one that scrolls right and arrow-button-left the one that scrolls left:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var bodyWidth = $( "body" ).width(),
  wWidth = $( window ).width(),
  step = 400,
  arrowButton = $( "#arrow-button" ),
  pos = 0;

 arrowButton.click(function() {
if ( pos < bodyWidth ) {
  pos += step;
} else {
  pos = 0; 
}

console.log(pos);

$('body').animate( { scrollLeft: pos }, 1000);
  });

$(document).ready(function() {
  var bodyWidth = $( "body" ).width(),
  wWidth = $( window ).width(),
  step = -400,
  arrowButton = $( "#arrow-button-left" ),
  pos = 0;

  arrowButton.click(function() {
if ( pos < bodyWidth - wWidth ) {
  pos += step;
} else {
  pos = 0; 
}

console.log(pos);

$('body').animate( { scrollLeft: pos }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You mind sharing your HTML as well?

Comment: Your `pos` variable is distinct between the two functions. When you click right your position goes to 400, when you click left it goes to -400. You need a single `pos` variable that both functions can access to maintain the actual position. The left arrow should be `pos - step`, and the right arrow should be `pos + step`.

Comment: @thepriebe that makes total sense and I'm here going "duh!" Do you have any idea how I can change the code for one position but two arrow buttons?

Comment: @thepriebe Oh, I just read better what you wrote and realized you already answered my question! Thank you!!!!

Comment: @AliceYang I'll post a possible solution below.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be in your if else condition.

```
if ( pos < bodyWidth - wWidth ) {
  pos += step;
} else {
  pos = 0; 
}
```

You're always jumping back to your initial position on hitting the left arrow. You may replace `pos = 0` through `pos -= step`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.
https://jsfiddle.net/4yberkho/1/

If it is going to scroll a fixed value you could simply animate the body by an increment or a decrement of the value

```
arrowButtonLeft = $( "#arrow-button-left" );

arrowButton = $( "#arrow-button" );

// Right arrow click
arrowButton.click(function(){

    // Animate the body to scroll right 400px
    $('body').stop().animate( { scrollLeft: '+=400px' }, 1000);

});

// Left arrow click
arrowButtonLeft.click(function(){

    // Animate the body to scroll left 400px
    $('body').stop().animate( { scrollLeft: '-=400px' }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying - I made the change but it still scrolls to the beginning. I also tried to replace the first pos = 0 with post+= step but it still doesn't seem to work...any thoughts?

Comment: @AliceYang You could try changing the pos += step; in the second if statement to pos -= step; ?

Comment: I got rid of the if else statement altogether but it seems that the problem is that I have two pos values for each button! No matter where the viewport is, the left arrow will try to reach -400 from pos = 0. Would you have any idea idea how to use one pos for both buttons?

Comment: You could try something like this:

Comment: @AliceYang Sorry updated my answer hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution for the pos variable being changed based on the step and relative position.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
var pos = 0;
var step = 400;
var bodyWidth = $( "body" ).width();
var wWidth = $( window ).width();
var nextArrowButton = $( "#arrow-button" );
var backArrowButton = $( "#arrow-button-left" );

nextArrowButton.click(function() {
  if ( pos < bodyWidth ) {
    pos += step;
  } else {
    pos = 0; 
  }
  console.log(pos);
 $('body').animate( { scrollLeft: pos }, 1000);
  });

backArrowButton.click(function() {
  if ( pos < bodyWidth ) {
    pos -= step;
  } else {
    pos = 0; 
  }
  console.log(pos);
  $('body').animate( { scrollLeft: pos }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is amazing.